# SQL queruy to read data from XML file

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

Below XML file I want to read the data for tag `<H.2>`
I am using below query but I am not able to get the data for `<H.2>` as its contains 2 child tag. I am able to get the data for `<H.1>`

```xml
<ECH> 
 <NCH> 
  <NBG> 
   <H.1>1</H.1> 
   <H.2> 
    <IT.1>1312</IT.1> 
    <BT.2>GD23</BT.2> 
   </H.2> 
  </NBG> 
  <NBG> 
   <H.1>1</H.1> 
   <H.2> 
    <IT.1>1312</IT.1> 
    <BT.2>GD23</BT.2> 
   </H.2> 
  </NBG> 
 </NCH> 
</ECH>
```

```sql
SELECT b.* 
FROM hospital a, 
     XMLTABLE('ECH//NCH//NBG//H.2' 
              PASSING a.xmlpayload 
              COLUMNS action VARCHAR2(20) PATH '.' ) b;
```

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: 1312 | GD23  1312 | GD23